# How to connect redis managed service [From Redis Cloud and not AWS/GCP] with redis-cli? Operation timed out

Tags: redis

I have created a redis memcached database on https://app.redislabs.com/ and trying to connect to that using command line. I am using:

`redis-cli -h <HOST> -p <PORT> -a <Password>`

But it keeps returning:

`Could not connect to Redis at <HOST:PORT>: Operation timed out`

Do we need to do any additional configurations to connect to Redis cloud server?

Answer (score 0):

This is the timeout error which means the redis instance is not reachable from your machine. Make sure the traffic is allowed from your machine to the redislab. In redislab you can define the network range for connectivity.

Also try to telnet to the port,`telnet <HOST> <PORT>` if its not connecting then its the connectivity issue only.